# Mindmap tool for knowledge base creation with file integration

Tags: windows, mind-mapping

I am currently writing my Master thesis and doing an empirical study. In order to keep track of all the papers, articles and files I read, create and study, I want to organize everything in a sort of Mind map.

This mindmap should be a Windows desktop application, because my files are pretty huge. Further, it should be able to let me draw a mindmap, add files (docs, pdfs, xls, jpgs) to nodes and link them with each other.

I already googled a lot and found "TheBrain 8" which looked nice at first. However, in the free version the user is unable to move nodes freely. Because of the high price and because I am a student I am sadly not able to get a pro licence :(

Is there a free or cheap windows software that does me allow to create a mindmap, attach files to it and freely move all nodes?

Would be very glad if you could help me out with this one, there has to be some tool like this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Freemind can link files to nodes, but moving the nodes is not 100% free. You can change the order and hierarchy of nodes. Would that be sufficient or do you really need 100% freedom in layout?

Comment: Microsoft OneNote might also be an option. There are student versions available. OneNote is very nice for research, because it typically also records the time and URL where you got information from. That really has benefits for the references section.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I searched a little more and found Docear which is great and works like Freemind but has even more functionalities. Thanks!

Comment: if you like Docear, you can answer your own question and accept it in 2 days. Like that, other people can benefit from the answer and we know it has been solved.